# Can't install PlayOnLinux

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: python-wxgtk2.8 but it is not installable or
                        python-wxgtk3.0 but it is not installable
               Depends: cabextract but it is not installable
               Depends: icoutils but it is not installable
               Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? How did you install PoL?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04     
get -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

will fix the issue. The needed packages will be installed.

You could install PoL an easier way from Ubuntu repositories by

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

but that could install not the very latest version.

Now you can remove the custom repository by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge playonlinux
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

this will install PoL from Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Thanks for the response i tried but the same error still comes up

Comment: It is possible that the version from pol repositories is not compatible.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: thanks for the help still have the error ill try rebooting

Comment: Maybe some repositories are not on. Check in System Settings -> Software & Updates that main, restricted, universe and multiverse are on.

Comment: You can install from the PoL repo too. But I do not think there is much difference.

Answer (score 2):

Go to software & updates and switch to main server.

```
sudo apt install -f && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install playonlinux
```

Ubuntu has playonlinux on it's repo. So you didn't have to add repositories by yourself.

Comment: same error comes up should i reboot or something else